# How in QGIS to place the signature of the latitude and longitude of the map corner in the layout?

Tags: qgis, layouts, grids-graticules, maps, bathymetry

It must be done as in the example.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (currently as of QGIS 3.20.2) only possible using a workaround.

1. Disable the coordinate drawing of your grid
2. Add a label widget and place it where you want to show the coordinates
3. Enter the following expression:

For X min:

```
to_dms(x_min(transform(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'),map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'x',3,'suffix')
```

For Y max:

```
to_dms(y_max(transform(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'),map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'y',3,'suffix')
```

Replace `'Map 1'` with the name of your map widget. Also you can use `x_max()` or `y_min()`, depending on the position you want to show.

Example:

[image]

PS: in case you do not need to transform the maps CRS, you can also go via "Dynamic Text -> Map Properties -> YourMapName -> YourMaxMinCoordinate" in your label widget, like:

[image]

Comment: Good day! Thanks for your feedback. But, unfortunately, your script does not work for me. The QGIS version is the same as what you wrote. Substituting my card ID values.

Comment: Can you elaborate "does not work" a little more?

Comment: below I posted what I am getting

Comment: Just tested again. Seems like `item_variables()` is a little sensitive about names. Try this: rename your map, then rename the maps name in the expression.

Comment: I understood why it doesn't work for me. I use a non-standard coordinate system, and for some reason it does not translate from it to a normal view. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do your coordinates change automatically when you change the map borders?

Comment: Kind of. You need to click on the text box (nothing more). It also should update when you export the map as .png, .pdf or sth else. Reason is that there is no option to automatically refresh all elements in print layout. Would sound nice as a feature request, but I guess that would be a performance overkill for QGIS.

Comment: Just beeing curios: what is your CRS? All by QGIS known systems should be transformed automatically to EPSG:4326.

Comment: I use a mercator projection with a standard parallel of 75 degrees. In QGIS, it was registered as a user one.